# ¿Traducción para "Thought Leader"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

Un `thought leader` viene a ser un visionario en una cierta industria. Estas personas son valoradas en la industria por sus opiniones informadas  y son reconocidas como autoridades en sus respectivas materias.

Los "thought leaders" no solo van varios pasos por delante de los demás, sino que son los que "tiran del carro" haciendo que la industria vaya hacia delante con innovadoras y revolucionarias ideas. Saben cómo hacer realidad sus ideas y convertirlas en éxitos de mercado.

La traducción directa al español, *líder de pensamiento*, me suena a "alto mando de una secta". "Líder de industria" suena un poquito mejor, pero no sé si captura todo lo que es un "thought leader" y quizá englobe a personalidades que son brillantes y exitosas en los negocios, pero no necesariamente "thought leaders".

No sé si hay una traducción aceptada para este término en español o si alguien puede proponer alguna que sea más pegadiza, rimbombante o inspiradora que las que yo he puesto de ejemplo.

Comment: Googleando "gestor de ideas", encontré esto: http://blogs.lavozdegalicia.es/serantes/?p=133

Comment: A mí se me ocurre _visionario_, en cuanto a que visualiza el futuro que mejor conviene a una empresa dada.

Comment: ¿líder intelectual?¿líder ideológico?

Comment: Nunca había visto este término, y me estaba preguntando cuál sería la diferencia entre *leader* y *thought leader*, así que chequeé con wikipedia.  Encontré que hay algo de controversia, y hay quienes lo descartan como  "meaningless management speak."  Todavía no sé qué aporta esta frase que no se puede lograr con *leader*.

Comment: @aparente001 ese es un buen punto. Por eso preguntaba si, en caso de que no haya una traducción ya aceptada, a alguien se le ocurre algo "rimbombante". Estos títulos son así a veces para llamr la atención aunque estén carentes de significado (como añadirle "executive" a lo que sea).

Comment: @Diego - Me gusta tu palabra  *rimbombante*.  (Muchas veces el cliente no va a quedar contento si se suprimen esas palabras extras....)

Answer (score 2):

De inmediato se me ocurre

> **Líder de opinión**

Se refiere desde luego a expertos en cierto tema, que además publican y frecuentemente expresan sus ideas, generalmente asociadas a una línea de pensamiento o ideología en su área de experiencia.

Se usa con frecuencia para describir a columnistas populares, publicados en periódicos de alta circulación y últimamente a quienes publican en nuevos medios electrónicos, y que tienen gran popularidad o *seguidores* en ellos (Twitter, YouTube, Blogs)

La característica de un ***líder de opinión***, sin embargo es su capacidad de **influir** en el pensamiento o ideas de quienes le siguen, y esto aplica en cualquier ámbito de discusión ya sea intelectual, político, técnico o simplemente ocio.

Answer (score 1):

Me aventuro con ésta:

> [**gurú**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ju4WKQL)
>
> Del sánscr. *gurú*, var. de *gurús*; propiamente 'pesado, grave'.
>
> **1**. m. En el hinduismo, maestro espiritual o jefe religioso.
>
> **2**. m. y f. Persona a quien se considera maestro o guía espiritual, o a quien se le reconoce autoridad intelectual.

No tengo antecedentes de que se use en otros países, pero en Chile es habitual desde hace unas dos décadas (aunque siento que tal vez tiene un tinte peyorativo, como de "iluminado").

Comment: No es mala aportación, pero "guru" existe también en inglés, con otras connotaciones. Puedes ser el gurú de UNIX o de lo que sea (te manejas como pez en el agua) pero un "thought leader" se diferenciaría en que no es un "usuario pasivo" sino que ayudaa mover la industria en cierta dirección (y esas connotaciones "gurú" no las tiene).

Comment: Un guru domina un tema mas alla de lo posible para cualquier mortal promedio, pero no necesariamente influye en el pensamiento de otros. de hecho, el arquetipo del guru es mas bien "pasivo" alguien a quien te acercas para obtener respuestas emanadas de su sabiduria. el *Thought Leader* (o lider de opinion) **activamente** discute, promueve y "evangeliza" sus ideas que pueden ser innovadoras y poco ortodoxas, en contraste con el guru.